# How can I set onclick listener in my recyclerview with cardview and retreive the data from firebase database when i click the recyclerview?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I have an activity named Categories (categories of vehicles) that retrieves the data from firebase (ex. cars, motorcycle) and The layout is consist of recyclerview with cardview. What I want to happen is, when I click one of the categories, I want to retrieve the list of that chosen category to the next activity. My problem is, I don't know how to implement the onclick listener.
here is the code for my CategoryActivty:

public class CategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
DatabaseReference reference;
RecyclerView recyclerView;
ArrayList<Categories> list;
MyAdapter adapter;

BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.myRecycler);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    list = new ArrayList<Categories>();

    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Categories");
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot:snapshot.getChildren())
            {
                Categories c= dataSnapshot.getValue(Categories.class);
                list.add(c);
            }
            adapter = new MyAdapter(CategoryActivity.this,list);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

        }
    });




    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottomNav);
    bottomNavigationView.setSelectedItemId(R.id.home);

    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {

            switch (menuItem.getItemId())
            {
                case R.id.home:
                    break;

                case R.id.notifications:
                    Intent intent1 = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,NotificationActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent1);
                    break;

                case R.id.info:
                    Intent intent2 = new Intent(HomeActivity.this,AboutActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent2);
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

```
This is for the Categories.java
```

public class Categories {

```
String name, image;

public Categories() {
}

public Categories(String name, String image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.image = image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getImage() {
    return image;
}

public void setImage(String image) {
    this.image = image;
}
```

}

and this is for the Adapter:

public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

```
Context context;
ArrayList <Categories> list;

public MyAdapter (Context c, ArrayList <Categories> l)
{
    context = c;
    list = l;
}


@NonNull
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    return new MyViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.cardview1,parent,false));
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.name.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    Picasso.get().load(list.get(position).getImage()).into(holder.image);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}
```

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

```
    TextView name;
    ImageView image;
   public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
       super(itemView);

       name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.categoryName);
       image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image1);

   }
```

}
}

please help me, it's my first time using android studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple way is add onClickListener inside onBindViewHolder

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener {
            // call listener or just start required activity with data
        }
```

Because you can`t send non plain type object to Activity you must implements Categories from Parcelable and later use intent.putExtra().